# Cannot get email from this php form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm making a email form on my website.
For some reason, I cannot get email from this form.

html

```
        <form method="POST" action="processor.php" id="contactform" onsubmit="return(validateForm());">
        <div>
            <label for="fname">First Name:<br></label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" class="required"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lname">Last Name:<br></label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" class="required"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="organization">Organization:<br></label>
            <input type="text" name="organization" id="organization" value="" class="required"/>
        </div>
         <div>
            <label for="email">Email:<br></label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="phone">Phone:<br></label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="required" />
        </div>          

        <div>
            <label for="message" style="line-height: 2;">Message:<br></label>
            <textarea rows="20" cols="20" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="submit-button myButton" value="Send" />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) > 7 || !strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
        die("Bad referer");
    $msg = "Website Message:\n\n\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $msg .= "Item: $key\n\n";
            foreach ($val as $v) {
                $v = stripslashes($v);
                $msg .= " $v\n\n";
            }
        } else {
            $val = stripslashes($val);
            $msg .= "$key: $val\n\n";
        }
    }
    $recipient = "test@example.com";
    $subject   = "Website Contact Form Filled Out";
    error_reporting(0);
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $msg)) {
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html");
    } else
        echo "An error occurred and the message could not be sent.";
} else
    echo "Bad request method";
?>
```

The thing is the PHP code works because the it worked with the other HTML form.
I am wondering the way of HTML coding is the reason or not.
If anybody know PHP and form well, please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: theres a lot wrong with this code, find a tutorial on sending mail from php

Comment: What is the exact problem? Also, indending your code would make it a lot more readable.

Comment: The problem is even I send the message with this form i don't get anything in my mailbox, even in spam box.

Comment: From your code, `$recipient = "test@example.com";` did you try with a real email address ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with my email. It worked with the other HTML code, but not with this HTML coding. I'm sure the div tag inside form tag won't cause a problem.

Comment: Enable error reporting and tell us what you find (see this: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors)

Comment: Is your PHP script getting executed? are you getting any of your echoed errors? is mail turned on in php.ini? Did you had breakfast before you started coding? ( ;) )

Comment: If you're not getting anything in your mailbox the problem must be with your `mail()` call. Elsewise you'd be getting a message with at least the subject filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print_r($_POST);
exit;
```

Before your code

```
// put it here
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) > 7 || !strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
            die("Bad referer");
    ....
```

If you will see variable contained email - then something wrong with your PHP script
And also - Enable showing errors (i.e. error reporting)

I saw, you said it's works perfectly with another form. Do i can look at code of this form, please?

Comment: Thank you Victor! I just figured it out that when I named ID and NAME of submit button as "submit", it didn't work. After I changed them to #submitbutton(ID) and submitBtn(name), it worked. Actually, I don't know why it works though.

Comment: No problem ;) Vote up if this comment was useful for you